# Facebook Common Objects not displaying on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

In my facebook app, there is a common object type news.read for a page which contains article. I used news.read object so that on user's timeline it will be posted as `User read an article on app`. When tested, the facebook is returning the publish `id` meaning it was a success. The problem is that its not displayed even on developer's timeline but is visible on developer's activity. I have experience publishing using custom object and actions. In Open graph pages under `Types` page, under `Action types` heading i have created `read article` . Am I missing something which have to be applied on pre-defined objects?

Comment: As you say its in activity and was posted, most probably it might have ended up in the [collection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/). Check it there

Comment: @AnveshSaxena: Have checked it. It's not present. I haven't created any collection for this action type yet.